# pouchdb is not defined in angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, pouchdb

I am using PouchDB in my AngularJS application.

Following are the steps that I follows to implement/access PouchDB in my AngularJS application.

1. Install angular-pouchdb via Bower:

   ```
   bower install --save angular-pouchdb
   ```
2. Add pouchdb as a module dependency in app.js:

   ```
   var application = angular.module("application", ["ui.router", "pouchdb"]);
   ```
3. Inject the pouchdb service in my application:

   ```
   application.factory("pouchDataAccessFactory", function (pouchdb) {
       var factory = {};
       var database = undefined;
       factory.createDatabase = function ()
       {
           database = pouchdb.create("memorydb")
               .then(function () { })
               .catch(function () { })
               .finally(function () { });
       }

       factory.destroyDatabase = function () {
           pouchdb.destroy("memorydb");
       }

       factory.insert = function (product) {
           database.put(product)
               .then(function (response) {
                   // Do something with the response 
               })
               .catch(function (error) {
                   // Do something with the error
               })
               .finally(function () {
                   // Do something when everything is done
               });
       }

       return factory;
   });
   ```
4. Call from HomeController

   ```
   application.controller("HomeController", function ($scope, pouchDataAccessFactory) {

       function initialize()
       {
           pouchDataAccessFactory.createDatabase();
       }
       debugger;
       initialize();
   });
   ```
5. Add angular-pouchdb.js and add reference in index.html

   ```
   <html>

   <head>

       <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
       <script src="Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
       <!--<script src="Scripts/pouchdb-3.6.0.js"></script>-->
       <script src="Scripts/angular-pouchdb.js"></script>

       <script src="App/app.js"></script>

       <script src="App/Controllers/HomeController.js"></script>

       <script src="App/Factory/PouchDBAccessFactory.js"></script>

       <link href="StyleSheets/AppStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />

   </head>

   <body>

       <div ng-app="application" ng-strict-di>
           <nav role="navigation">
               <ul>
                   <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
                   <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
               </ul>
           </nav>

           <div ui-view>
           </div>

       </div>

   </body>

   </html>
   ```

**It gives following error:**

> ReferenceError: pouchdb is not defined at Object.factory.createDatabase

I follow following link:
https://github.com/wspringer/angular-pouchdb

Comment: You should uncomment `<script src="Scripts/pouchdb-3.6.0.js"></script>` that would needed for `angular-pouchdb` i think

Answer (score 0):

From the doc you have to respect the case : `pouchDB` and not `pouchdb`

```
angular.factory('factory', function(pouchDB) {
  var db = pouchDB('name');
});
```

As said in comment as well, check if you set the right script in your html code

Comment: @pankajparkar he installed the official angular-pouch from bower , not the fork from wspringer on github, so the doc is at https://github.com/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb. this is the right doc

Comment: that means you are saying the 1st part of the code but why `$window.pouchDB`

Comment: Please keep reading the following part "Writing $scope.$apply each time is laborious and we haven't even mentioned exception handling or $digest already in progress errors.

angular-pouchdb handles $scope.$apply for you by wrapping PouchDB's promises with $q. You can then use its promises as you would with any Angular promise, including the .finally method (not in the A+ spec)."

Go to Usage part and check service usage